# Using FluentValidation's ruleset feature on Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I'd like to use the [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/)'s ruleset feature in a Web API project, because I don't want to have to perform the validations manually, so I'm using [`FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.WebApi/FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.cs#L44) to add FluentValidation to the [`ModelValidatorProviders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.validation.modelvalidatorprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) so that I that my models are automatically validated before being sent to the action method.

Till this point everything is great and working correctly, but what if I decide to use the ruleset feature? When it comes to automatically validation the examples you see on the web makes use of the [`CustomizeValidatorAttribute`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.Mvc4/CustomizeValidatorAttribute.cs) like so:

```
public ActionResul Something([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "RuleName")]MyModel myModel)
```

But the problem is that CustomizeValidator is only available for ASP.NET MVC, so what should I do in order to have at least a similar behavior on Web API?

Comment: When a Web API project is created it has also references to MVC, the steps for using CustomizeValidator are the same as in an MVC project: adding FluidValidation for MVC nugget, registering the provider in global.asax. It's working for controller methods returning ActionResult. I have not tried it for ApiController though.

Comment: This might help: http://devthings.com.ua/fluent-validation-with-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I tried several things and could not get it to work.. I was able to create a ruleset but the ModelState is always valid.. not sure what's happening.

Comment: The only way I got the auto validation to work was by setting the validator before the class `[Validator(typeof(MyCustomValidator))]`.  It looks like you already have that working, so I would just suggest creating a validator that only does the rules in your ruleset.  Though, I see the possibility of you needing to have your model needing to be checked in a different fashion as well for another method, so that may not work for you.  Sadly, Web API does not have the same behavior as MVC for FluentValidation.

Comment: first upload your webapi code, ActionResult is part of mvc. Web api works differently and would have different issues. when i see attribute on parameter in an mvc method that was changed to webapi my intuition screams that this is a model binder issue, although at this point i can only guess